# Is there an autorespond email function for profile form sign ups (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, profile

I have a sign up form that adds users to a group- essentially a mailing list which also saves other information about the subscriber. It's a civiCRM 'profile' form.

This all works OK. A user adds their information to the form and their information is saved in a group called members. Now my client would like to automatically email them when a new user signs up. There doesn't seem to be any way to do this 'out of the box'. Someone has raised this issue with regards to Joomla before [HERE](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/933/autoresponder-for-filling-out-profile). But, being reasonably new to web development and civiCRM and don't know how to do this with my WORDPRESS installation.

I think you have to do something with hooks and create a wordpress plugin? http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Hook+Reference

I guess I'm wondering whether someone has already done this? OR they can point me to instructions that a newbie may be able to understand?

I'm using wordpress 4.1.5 and civiCRM 4.6.2

Answer (score 3):

Third option is to use the CiviCRM extension CiviRules. It allows you to set up a rule (in this case when contact is added to group), a condition (group is xxx) and an action (send email). You will have to add the send email to a specific address option (or wait for someone else to sponsor this action development as there is already a GitHub issue for it).
More information on http://redmine.civicoop.org/projects/civirules/wiki and you can get the extension from https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules

The CiviRules extension is now live at MAF Norge and will be tested by Amnesty International Flanders.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into using the CiviCRM/Mailchimp Integration Extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/mailchimp-civicrm-integration

When you add someone to a Group in CiviCRM, it can sync them to a List in Mailchimp. I believe you could set up an auto-responder there.

Perhaps a complex work around, but thought it might help you out.

In Drupal land, I would use CiviCRM Entity and the Rules modules to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off doing this with a CiviCRM extension rather than a WordPress plugin.  I wrote an extension that does this (amongst other things) a while back.  It's available here: https://github.com/PalanteJon/coop.palantetech.module.cpehn.joinnetworkcheckbox/tree/automatic-email-only

I just created a new branch called "automatic email only" where I stripped out all the code that's not relevant to this question.

You'll need to customize this extension a bit to only fire when people join a certain group(s).  It will send the "Welcome" automated message at **Mailings menu > Headers, Footers, and Automated Messages**.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have much/any experience with extensions. I can see the branch 'automatic email only' but don't know what to do with it.